# Odd behavior in Unity 5.1 2d project prefabs

Tags: unity

I am very worried something is corrupt in my project. I am making a 2d top-down rogue-like and am currently using prefabs to generate enemies from. I have started running into an issue where I get a null reference error when trying to iterate a collection of enemies after doing anything on the prefabs, even just selecting one in the editor. If I drag any of the enemy prefabs into the scene then immediately delete it I am fine until I touch a prefab in the inspector again. at one point I was getting "iHasError" 6 times with no info but the unity reinstall fixed that so far

I have tried:

```
•Deleting the library folder
•Doing a Reimport All
•Uninstalling and reinstalling Unity
•Reloading the project from a few days ago
•Removed a bunch of animations added this weekend
•Commenting out everything I had done recently in the Enemy script
•Googled for a couple hours and looking for things that seem similar
```

My prefab is structured:

```
•Gameobject
•Sprite Renderer
•Enemy (Script) About 500 lines
•Animator (simple 2-sprite swap animation)
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Mike B

Comment: Unity 5 is so buggy atm... I've been having issues with the animation window and the scripts in my project view. For some reason I can't even rename a script after its created :s constantly reverts itself back to the original

Comment: After further troubleshooting I have found this only happens if the prefab is tagged (I tag them "Enemy" so I can build a collection in code

Comment: Send unity a bug report